# Why are BottomSheetScaffoldLayout's sheetContent touch events ignored when the sheet is partially expanded?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

BottomSheetScaffoldLayout's sheetContent touch events are ignored when the sheet is partially expanded

Touch events such as clicking on an element in the sheetContent does not work. I've noticed when the sheet is in the initial peek state, touch events work. When the sheet is full screen, touch events work. However, if the bottom sheet is partially expanded sheetContent touch events are not working.

```kotlin
val peekHeightPx by remember { mutableStateOf(peekHeight) }

val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetContent = {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
        ) {
            items(8) {
                Text(
                    text = "Item $it",
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { manageFleetClicked.invoke() })
            }
        }
    },
    sheetPeekHeight = peekHeightPx,
) {
    // content 
}
```

Comment: sheetGesturesEnabled = true, // Enable touch events in the sheetContent
  
By setting sheetGesturesEnabled to true, you enable touch events to propagate to the sheetContent even when the bottom sheet is partially expanded.